# Liquibase: How to specify schema name within databaseChangeLog

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, database-schema

How to specify schema name within xml databaseChangeLog? E.g. I have created a new schema with the following changelog, after which I want to select newly created schema to populate changes.

```xml
<databaseChangeLog>
    <changeSet author="quickstart-1" id="quickstart-1">
        <sql>
            CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name AUTHORIZATION schema_name_user;
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for future readers

```xml
<changeSet author="author_name" id="create_table">
    <createTable tableName="table_name" catalogName="bigquery" schemaName="mydataset">
        <column name="id" type="INT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="event_name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```